# Own program prints different directory sizes than DU

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I made a little c++ project to print the sizes of directories and files ordened. However, I noticed that I get a difference in size for what du reports and what my program, using boost::filesystem, reports.  Could anyone tell me what kind of error I might be making, I have tried looking and debugging, but I'm just not seeing it.

https://github.com/jelmew/printSIzeTree

Kind regards,
Jelmew

Edit:
Nautilus prints the same size as my program does.

Comment: On StackOverflow everything must be in the question. I mean the minimal source code of your algorithm, expected and actual data. Remember the main goal of a question is to help other readers with the same problem.

Comment: Try working with just a single file and work out exactly how it differs - are you sure you're looking at size of file rather than size of file on disk?

Comment: Does the filesystem  have automatic compression lilke zfs or btrfs?

Comment: Have you tried du --apparent-size https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173947/du-s-apparent-size-vs-du-s

Comment: That's it. Doh, I forgot that du prints size on disk.